# Python - neural network training loss and validation loss values

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, text-classification

I have a question about my training loss and validation loss for a neural network in python using pytorch. I am using bert to classify labels for some given text.

I have about 14k text records with 20 unique labels - where some labels are more frequent than others.

I use about 25% as my validation set and use strafification when performing train_test_splits.

My learning rate is 1e-6

attention_probs_dropout_prob=0.2

hidden_dropout_prob=0.2

There is no data leakeage as I did not impute any values

While training my model I notice few things.

1. training loss remains higher than validation loss
2. with each epoch both losses go down but training loss never goes below the validation loss even though they are close
3. Example

|  | epoch 8 | epoch 50 | epoch 100 | epoch 200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| training loss | 2.9 | 1.18 | .98 | .75 |
| validation loss | 2.4 | 1.0 | .67 | .45 |
| F1 score - weighted | .55 | .75 | .86 | .90 |

4. As noticed we see that the training loss decreases a bit at first but then slows down, but validation loss keeps decreasing with bigger increments

can someone explain to me what is going on with how this model is learning? My understanding is that it is not performing well based on the training loss and validation loss values. Usually my values should be lower with the training loss below validation loss

any input is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Hey there, have you shuffled the data before your train/test split?

Comment: Hi Amit - I have not shuffled the data before train/test split. I do specify the random state and I was thinking that would take care of the shuffling right? - thank you. I will try the model again with shuffle = True within train_test_split

Comment: Yup, give that a shot. Everything else seems to be okay, so the only other thing I can think of is that there is some data toward the end of your dataset (this is being used as your validation data) that has no representation in your training set.

Comment: Thank you so much Amit! I am giving it a try and will report back! thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: If you are using data augmentation on your train set and not your validation set this can occur, in which case it's not a problem per se.

Comment: Fyi it's better to ask non-programming questions on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.